# Moodle Form processing array on submit

Tags: php, moodle

I'm working on processing data returned from a form but because I've had to manually assign ids to the select dropdowns (so that I can attach a help button to the headings) I can't find an example to work from.

The array being returned looks like this:

```
  [10]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [11]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [12]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [20]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [21]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [22]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["comments"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["submitbutton"]=>
  string(12) "Save changes"
```

What I need to do is group all that start with a unique number (i.e. 1,2...) and ignore the comments and submitbutton elements.
In other words, I want it to look like this:

```
id = 1
    criteria0 = 0
    criteria1 = 0
    criteria2 = 0

id = 2
    criteria0 = 0
    criteria1 = 0
    criteria2 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I would just use a delimiter, eg:

In the form

```
foreach (array(1,2) as $id) {
    foreach (array(1,2,3) as $criteria) {
        $key = $id . '_' . $criteria;
        $options[$key] = "Your description for id $id, criteria $criteria";
    }
}

$attributes = array('multiple' => 'multiple', 'size' => 10);

$form->addElement('select', 'criteria', get_string('criteria', 'component'), $options, $attributes);
```

Then in the results

```
$formdata = $mform->get_data();

...

$results = array();

foreach ($formdata->criteria[$key] as $key => $value) {
    list($id, $criteria) = explode('_', $key);
    $results[$id][$criteria] = $value;
}
```

Also for reference, Moodle has a `selectgroups` field type. You will still need to use a unique key but you can group the options.

```
foreach (array(1,2) as $groupid) {
    foreach (array(1,2,3) as $criteria) {
        $key = $groupid . '_' . $criteria;
        // Use a group.
        $options[$groupid][$key] = "Your description for id $groupid, criteria $criteria";
    }
}

$attributes = array('multiple' => 'multiple', 'size' => 10);

// Use selectgroups.
$form->addElement('selectgroups', 'criteria', get_string('criteria', 'component'), $options, $attributes);
```